# slf4j logger info format

Tags: java, apache, logging

I'm trying to generate a 'nice' log message with using escaping characters or an xml pattern etc.

What I'd like to output is something along the lines of:

```
ABAS : value
B    : value
Cse  : value
```

I've achieved this using \t but I figure there must be a cleaner way.  I've looked at .info which takes an argument and using the {} as a way of inserting the values but I can't seem to find out how to add the line breaks or tabbing.

so far I have

```
logger.info(A : {} \nBasdas : {} \nC : asds ) and so on.
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slf4j is the log frontend and only intended to provide log level, message etc. to the backend, most likely logback in your case. You shouldn't format your messages in the frontend expecting any special format in the actual log output, because exactly that can be somewhat freely configured by the backend one uses. Especially indentation over some independent lines doesn't work, because you can't know how lines start, if your logger names are part of lines, where the msg is printed within a line and all that stuff. Just look at the [logback configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) and what is possible, how do you want to tell as the log message issuing programmer which of those possibilities are used during runtime in any environment of your software? You simply can't and therefore shouldn't assume too much.

So what you want is simply not possible, besides embedding tabs or newlines there's nothing to format log messages in slf4j for a good reason. And you can't count on your tabs as well, because how those are presented to a user looking at your log file depends totally on the text editor or whatever one uses. It may even convert tabs to spaces, show them with a width of 1 or 10 or whatever.

Log statements spanning multiple lines may be considered [bad practice](http://juliusdavies.ca/logging.html#grep) at all.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. I've formatted a string and added that to the log for the time being. It's due a code review shortly as demo coming up and may well need to be placed on one line. Thanks again very much. :)